# AJAX post values becomes boolean after reaching the CI controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I been searching in google for days but still got no answer to solve this. I have this ajax function which update a record in mysql database. When I use ajax to insert a new record, everything is smooth but when I update this record thru ajax it gives me 403 Forbidden response. When I use var_dump to check the values pass from ajax all values became boolean. Below is my code, hope you can help me.

Ajax Update

```
$.ajax({
    url:'updateDeal',
    async:false,
    type:'post',
    data:{
        dealId:dealId,
        dealName:dealName,
        dealLocation:dealLocation,
        dealCategory:dealCategory,
        dealDescription:description,
        dealValidDate:dealValidDate,
        dealRegularPrice:dealRegularPrice,
        dealPromoPrice:dealPromoPrice,
        dealHighlights:tourHighlight,
        dealInclusion:inclusions,
        dealItenerary:itinerary,
        dealAdditionalServices:additional,
        isPromo:isPromo,
        isPublish:isPublish
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.image-loader').show();
    },
    success:function(results){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(results);
        if(!obj.hasError){
            $('.image-loader').hide();
            window.location = 'success?id=2';
        }
    }
});
```

Contoller

```
public function updateDeal(){

        $data = array(
            "Id"                    => $this->input->post('dealId'),
            "dealName"              => $this->input->post('dealName'),
            "dealLocation"          => $this->input->post('dealLocation'),
            "dealCategory"          => $this->input->post('dealCategory'),
            "dealDescription"       => $this->input->post('dealDescription'),
            "dealValidDate"         => $this->input->post('dealValidDate'),
            "dealRegularPrice"      => $this->input->post('dealRegularPrice'),
            "dealPromoPrice"        => $this->input->post('dealPromoPrice'),
            "dealHighlights"        => $this->input->post('dealHighlights'),
            "dealInclusion"         => $this->input->post('dealInclusion'),
            "dealItenerary"         => $this->input->post('dealItenerary'),
            "dealAdditionalServices" => $this->input->post('dealAdditionalServices'),
            "isPromo"               => $this->input->post('isPromo'),
            "isPublished"           => $this->input->post('isPublish')
        );
        var_dump($data);

    }
```

RESULT

```
array(14) {
  ["Id"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealName"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealLocation"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealCategory"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealDescription"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealValidDate"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealRegularPrice"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealPromoPrice"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealHighlights"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealInclusion"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealItenerary"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["dealAdditionalServices"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isPromo"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isPublished"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($this->input->post());` will prove much more useful. Please update your question with this data. It's possible that you need to do this `'dealId':dealId,` so that javascript doesn't get confused between variables and index names.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I tried your suggestion but it gave me same result. I change the variable name and check the output by using var_dump in each input->post. But I think the problem is not the ajax because I notice all responce has the status code of 403 Forbidden

Comment: That does not make sense because getting a 403 : forbidden would imply that you are never actually able to see the output which you posted in your question. I think you should take a closer look at Mohmmad's answer because he is on the right track. If you simply `echo 'hello world';` in that function and get rid of the rest of the code then what do you get when you visit www.yourwebsite.com/controllerName/updateDeal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, its the mod_security who is keep on blocking the parameters. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is somethings confusion on the url on while sending an ajax request.

try with this in ajax request:

```
url : 'yourcontrollername/updateDeal';
```

Comment: Hi @Mohmmad, I already tried that but still give me 403 response

Comment: Can you show me the form or view so that we can find the issue